# Put in NULL positions of a matrix the content of another matrix (list content)

Tags: r, matrix, merge

Having  `m1` (matrix 1):

```
[,1]
200
NULL
NULL
300
NULL
NULL
400
NULL
NULL
```

and `m2`:

```
 [,1]
    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
```

We want to obtain the following result:

```
 [,1]
    200
    1
    2
    300
    3
    4
    400
    5
    6
```

Therefore any element of m2 has to fit NULL positions of m1. Merge, join, append... is not obviously working, unless there is an argument for that case.

```
m1<-matrix(c(200,NA,NA,300,NA,NA,400,NA,NA), nrow = 9, ncol = 1) #I usually get NULL values in my code results

m2<-matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,6), nrow = 6, ncol = 1)
```

Any ideas are welcome and rewarded!

Comment: `m1[is.na(m1)] <- m2`

Comment: It's working, but what about if I have NULL positions on my matrix? is.null ?

Comment: You cannot have NULL elements in a matrix. NA is not the same as NULL.

Comment: I can only reiterate: You can't have NULL elements in a matrix. You should provide the output of dput for your matrix. Maybe you have a character matrix where some elements are the string "NULL".

Comment: Ok, understood. But then, why I got NULL (literally) in those positions? it is something that R does normally when creating a new matrix with empty spaces?

Comment: DO you have a list elements in matrix.  In that case, do `m1[] <- Map(function(x, y) {x[is.null(x)] <- y; x}, m1, m2)`

Comment: This is exciting @akrun, that's what I was looking for. However I need time to understand what you have done. The thing is that wave objects only admit list and matrix class to play with, so it is complicted to deal with this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `matrix` elements are `list` elements.  So, we need to loop through individual elements with `Map` (to replace the corresponding values from the second matrix)

```
m1[] <- Map(function(x, y) {x[is.null(x)] <- y; x}, m1, m2)
```

#### Update

Based on the example showed in the OP's post with `NA`s, it is possible that the 'm2' length is equal to the number of `NULL` elements in  'm1'.  In that case, we can assign based on a logical index created by looping over the elements of 'm1'

```
m1[sapply(m1, is.null)] <- m2
```

Comment: @akrun `m1[]` what is this bracket for?

Comment: @YOLO Bracket is to preserve the structure

Comment: @akrun, my apologies for that but this is not working. I got the error `Warning message:
In mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) :
  longer argument not a multiple of length of shorter
` and I checked all data several times in different processes. So finally I used IceCreamToucan solution and it works properly. I got a matrix completely random from the second sequence of my data.However, what happens with your solution? Could be improved?

Comment: @fina  It is based on the assumption that you have list elements as elements of your matrix and m2 is also a matrix with the same dimensions.  Please check the `str(m1)` and `str(m2)`.

Comment: @fina Based on the example you showed in the post.  It could be that the 'm2' length is equal t the number of NULL elements in m1.  In that case, the updated solution should work